# Rails error creating database with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

the first time when postgresql is installed in my local machine i created a user "user1" using the following command :

```
$ sudo su postgres -c psql
postgres=# CREATE ROLE user1 SUPERUSER LOGIN;
postgres=# \q
```

then setup my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: appname_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: user1
  password:
```

and all work fine, so today i created a new app then i did the same steps (creating a new user "user2" and modify my database.yml)

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: application2_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: user2
  password:
```

but when i try to create the database

```
$ rake db:create:all
```

i get this error :

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "application2"
```

i tried to fix the problem by adding   `host: localhost` to my `database.yml` but now i get another error which is :

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

can someone explains to me what means this error, and why the first time when i created the first user it doesn't show me this error ? then i will be thankful to know the solution as well.

thank you

Comment: Show the contents of your `pg_hba.conf`, and show the exact text of the *new* `database.rb` as well as the old one.

Comment: ok i added my database.yml but pg_hba.conf is empty

Comment: If you connect through `localhost` your pg installation needs to be accepting TCP/IP connections. Look up the listen_addresses parameters in `postgresql.conf`: it is commented out by default but you need to enable it. Then in `pg_hba.conf` you need to have at least one line to indicate that connections to databases over TCP/IP are allowed, using the `trust` authentication method (i.e. no passwords supplied). SIGHUP the server to read the new configuration with `pg_ctl reload`.

Answer (score 0):

I have already faced this problem and fixed it.

**I think, It will be helpful to you.**

please find 'pg_hba.conf' and `postgresql.conf` files.

generally, pg_hba.conf and `postgresql.conf` files located at `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/`.

put `local all all md5' in pg_hba.conf and save it.

open `postgresql.conf` file and if `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` and `port = 5432` line are commented. then uncomment to it.

Finally restart to pg server and try to create database.